# Unable to launch squirrel client

Tags: squirrel-sql

Unable to launch squirrel client.. When I hit on squirrel jar , it flashes launch pop up window and then disappears. I am using windows 7 enterprise 64 bit

I have set the Java Home path

**When I launch squirrel-sql.bat.. I get below error:-The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Root Drive of Atlas environment = C:
The system cannot find the path specified.
"SQUIRREL_CP="C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\squirrel-sql.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\a
ntlr.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\asm-attrs.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\asm
.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\cglib.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\commons-cli
.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\commons-codec.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\com
mons-collections.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\commons-httpclient.jar";"C:\development\installation
s\SquirrelSQL\lib\commons-logging.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\dom4j.jar";"C:\development\installa
tions\SquirrelSQL\lib\ejb3-persistence.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\forms.jar";"C:\development\ins
tallations\SquirrelSQL\lib\fw.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\hibernate-annotations.jar";"C:\developm
ent\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\hiber
nate-entitymanager.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\hibernate.jar";"C:\development\installations\Squir
relSQL\lib\jxl.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\log4j.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\l
ib\nanoxml.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\openide-loaders.jar";"C:\development\installations\Squirre
lSQL\lib\openide.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\org-netbeans-modules-editor-fold.jar";"C:\developmen
t\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\org-n
etbeans-modules-editor-util.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\org-netbeans-modules-editor.jar";"C:\deve
lopment\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\spring-beans.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\spring-context-sup
port.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\spring-context.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\li
b\spring-core.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_bg_BG.jar";"C:\development\installations\S
quirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_cs_CZ.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_de_DE.jar";"C:\develop
ment\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_es.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_fr.ja
r";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_it_IT.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\s
quirrel-sql_pt_BR.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_ru.jar";"C:\development\installations\
SquirrelSQL\lib\squirrel-sql_zh_CN.jar";"C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\stringtemplate.jar";"C:\developmen
t\installations\SquirrelSQL\lib\syntax.jar";"""**

Comment: How did you set JAVA HOME?

Comment: In environment variable, I have set the Java_Home as my jdk installation folder. Also in System variable I have set the path

Comment: Update your question with details please.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I have update the query.. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: When you type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from a DOS prompt, what do you see?  Maybe Squirrel still can't find Java.

Comment: C:\development\installations\SquirrelSQL>echo %Java_HOME%

C:\Shashank\Softwares\jdk1.8.0_92